# Observable array prop change

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

how can i observe an array of interfaces. So I have declared an interfaace:

```
export interface IBox {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Show: boolean;
}
```

And in my `componentWillMount()`:

```
public componentWillMount() {
    this.data = observable(this.props.boxes as IBox[]);
}
```

how can I evoke render if the value of Show is changed?

Answer (score 0):

By default mobx observers all properties in an object when object is turned into observable: https://mobx.js.org/refguide/object.html

So when you do:

```
this.data.push({
  Id: 0,
  Name: '',
  Show:false
});
this.data[0].Show = true; // show is now observed.
```

what does not work?

```
var obj = {
  Id: 0,
  Name: '',
  Show:false
};
this.data.push(obj);
obj.Show = true; // show is not observed!.
```

also this does not work, see: https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html

```
this.data.push({});
this.data[0].Show = true; // since property didn't exist when added, it is not observed.
```

The array should trigger that a model inside was changed and thus update/re-render the right component.

make sure that the component that uses the data has `@observer`. (Otherwise it wont trigger re-render). another solution would be to `mobx.toJS(this.data)` in the observed component and give this result as props to non-observed components.

Comment: Typo: make sure that the component that uses the data has `@observer` and not `@observe`